# Number of processing units available less than online processors

Tags: ubuntu, cpu

On an Ubuntu based Linux, when I run the [nproc](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/nproc-invocation.html) command, it prints 2. But when I run `nproc --all` it prints 8.

This means only 2 of the 8 online processors are available for use? How do I get all of the 8 online processors to become available? Is it controlled by a config?

Answer (score 2):

Can you run the following in the same shell where you're running `nproc`:

```
cat /proc/$$/limits
```

Result:

```
Limit                     Soft Limit           Hard Limit           Units
Max cpu time              unlimited            unlimited            seconds
Max file size             unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max data size             unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max stack size            8388608              unlimited            bytes
Max core file size        0                    unlimited            bytes
Max resident set          unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max processes             15795                15795                processes
Max open files            65536                65536                files
Max locked memory         65536                65536                bytes
Max address space         unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max file locks            unlimited            unlimited            locks
Max pending signals       15795                15795                signals
Max msgqueue size         819200               819200               bytes
Max nice priority         0                    0
Max realtime priority     0                    0
Max realtime timeout      unlimited            unlimited            us
```

Can you try this command to see if any of the cpu's are offline?

```
grep "" /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/online
```

Result:

```
# grep "" /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/online
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/online:1
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/online:1
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/online:1
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu4/online:1
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu5/online:1
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu6/online:1
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu7/online:1
```

If any of the CPU's is offline, you can turn it on by (for example CPU3) and try running `nproc` again:

```
echo 1 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/online
```

To turn them all on can you try:

```
for x in /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/online; do
  echo 1 >"$x"
done
```

Can you try the 8 commands independently one by one (if `permission denied` try with `sudo`):

```
echo 1 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/online
echo 1 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/online
echo 1 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/online
echo 1 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu4/online
echo 1 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu5/online
echo 1 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu6/online
echo 1 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu7/online
```

Comment: I am already logged in as root user. Anyways I did `sudo nproc` and still got 2.

Comment: @RBK updated my response can you try the other commands?

Comment: I've pasted the output of the commands in pastebin: http://pastebin.com/GEW1yw9J.  The grep said no such file. Trying to echo 1 into online gave permission denied(though I am root user).

Comment: @RBK: What OS do you use? Can you run `ls -al /sys/devices/system/cpu`. Or try looking around inside for somewhere where you will see cpu2, cpu3, cpu4, cpu5, etc.

Comment: I've updated the pasetbin with the comment from your last comment. The OS I use is a custom Linux based on Ubuntu.

Comment: Can you run `ls -al /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0`

Comment: Yes, updated pastbin with the output of the command.

Comment: Ok try running the last command I added to my post? Can you also post the contents of `/etc/default/grub` to see if you have `maxcpus` set on your kernel parameters.

Comment: It says no such file or directory. Updated pastebin with output.

Comment: pasted grub's contents. I dont see maxcpus in there.

Comment: Ok can you try the 8 commands independently as per my latest post update.

Comment: Yes, tried it independently, one by one. I am getting `Permission denied`.

Comment: Are you running in a virtual machine? Docker container, or other? Are there settings set by the host on your environment?

Comment: @RBK: Can you also try the 8 commands but putting `sudo` in front to see if you still get `Permission denied`?

Comment: I get the same error with sudo. I am not sure if this machine is a VM. I should ask my sys admin. Thanks for patiently debugging it so far!

Comment: Got it confirmed that the machine is not a VM but an actual physical machine.